# FTP:Upload file to FTP and verify

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, ftp

I am using VBS to

1. Upload a file to FTP
2. Verify the upload process

I am using the method which creates a text file, fills it with the appropriate command and then execute it using ftp.exe in windows.

```
            FTPCommand = "%systemroot%\System32\ftp.exe -s:session.txt"
            FTPCommand = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(FTPCommand)
            objshell.Run FTPCommand,, vbTrue
            fso.DeleteFile "session.txt", vbTrue
```

Part 1 is done using this code:

```
            Set SessionFile = fso.OpenTextFile("session.txt", 2, vbTrue)
            With SessionFile
                .WriteLine "open  abcd.com"
                .WriteLine "username"
                .WriteLine "pwd"
                .WriteLine "cd /Test/Test1"
                .WriteLine "put """ & File.Path & """"
                .WriteLine "quit"
                .Close
            End With

            FTPCommand = "%systemroot%\System32\ftp.exe -s:session.txt"
            FTPCommand = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(FTPCommand)
            objshell.Run FTPCommand,, vbTrue
            fso.DeleteFile "session.txt", vbTrue
```

And Part 2 is done using this code:

```
            Set SessionFile = fso.OpenTextFile("session.txt", 2, vbTrue)
            With SessionFile
                .WriteLine "open  abcd.com"
                .WriteLine "username"
                .WriteLine "pwd"
                .WriteLine "cd /Test/Test1"
                .WriteLine "ls"
                .WriteLine "close"
                .WriteLine "bye"
                .Close
            End With
            FTPCommand = "%systemroot%\System32\ftp.exe -s:session.txt"
            FTPCommand = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(FTPCommand)

            set ObjExec=objshell.exec(FTPCommand)
            DO WHILE ObjExec.status=0 : wscript.sleep 50 : LOOP
            StrTemp=ObjExec.stdout.readall

            IF instr(1,StrTemp,File.Name,1)<>0 THEN
                AlertMessage = AlertMessage & vbTab & "STATUS: UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            ELSE
                AlertMessage = AlertMessage & vbTab & "STATUS: UPLOAD FAILED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            END IF
            fso.DeleteFile "session.txt", vbTrue
```

The problem is that (in part 2 code) the code after

```
            DO WHILE ObjExec.status=0 : wscript.sleep 50 : LOOP
```

never returns.So the file gets uploaded but the code to check the status never returns.
The session.txt file does not get delete and when I execute the command

```
%systemroot%\System32\ftp.exe -s:session.txt
```

manually it indeed shows me the list of files (because of ls command).

I have 3 questions:

1. Why it does not return. Where to start debugging from?
2. Is there anyway I can upload the file and check its status(maybe by
   the error code returned by the ftp command after the "put" command).
3. Is there is an incorrect directory specified in the code to upload
   file, the cd command fails and it incorrectly "puts" the file in the
   root folder.  same goes for the code checking the file upload. So
   even if the directory specified in wrong, the program returns it as
   successful

**Edit 1:** 
I tried it using

```
.WriteLine "cd /Test"
```

and it worked.  Is that directory switching (two folders deep)causing the problem ?

**Edit 2:**
I ran the ls command manually and it ran fine.  The output is:

```
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 586493 bytes received in 4.28Seconds 137.00Kbytes/sec.
```

Is 586493 bytes too much for this ?

I believe the problem may be:
1)The large no of files returned by LS command.
2)The directory structure I am accessing.

**Edit:3**
From this [microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960246) website it looks like the above point 1 is the culprit:

> A console application's StdOut and StdErr streams share the same
>   internal 4KB buffer. In addition, the WshScriptExec object only
>   provides synchronous read operations on these streams. Synchronous
>   read operations introduce a dependency between the calling script
>   reading from these streams and the child process writing to those
>   streams, which can result in deadlock conditions.

Comment: It would probably be easier to debug by manually calling `FTP.EXE` and typing in the commands. Start with `ftp ftp.site.com`, it will ask for your username and password, then you just follow the script from there.

Comment: The only way I know to verify that the file was properly uploaded would be to download it, and compare that to the original file. To insure that it's transferred properly, you can set the ASCII or BINARY switches, depending on whether it's a text or binary file. Doing such is easy, you simply send the text `ascii` or `binary` before you transfer the file. Failure to do so can cause unexpected problems as `ftp` handles the transfers differently.

Comment: Like I said, if i manually run the commands it runs perfectly fine (586493 bytes received in 4.28Seconds). The problem is that the VBS somehow does not return the results back. I dont know where to start debugging.

Comment: Does execution ever get past the `DO WHILE ObjExec.status=0 : wscript.sleep 50 : LOOP` line?

Comment: NO, the line DO WHILE ObjExec.status=0 : wscript.sleep 50 : LOOP does not ever finish execution. ObjExec.status never becomes zero I guess.

Comment: No, it looks to me as though `ObjExec.status` never **stops** being zero. That is where I would focus my attention. Why don't you make the loop watch something else, like the keyboard or a file that you can delete, and have the loop print out the value of `ObjExec.status`. That way you can see if it changes at all during execution. It's probably not going to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the way you read the stdout from the process. I use this technique succesfully as follows, sorry, I have no time to adapt your script and try it out, so that is up to you.

The following executes a ping to check if the server is online.

```
Function IsOnline(Address) 
  Dim strText 
  IsOnline = False 
  Set oExecObj = oShell.Exec("%comspec% /c ping -a -n 1 -w 20 " & Address) 
  Do While Not oExecObj.StdOut.AtEndOfStream 
    strText = oExecObj.StdOut.ReadAll() 
    If Instr(strText, "Reply from") > 0 Then 
      IsOnline = True 
      Exit Function 
    End If 
  Loop 
End Function
```

Comment: even if you get a "Reply from" it doesn't mean that the host is up: sometimes you get a reply from the router, informing you that the remote network is unreachable

Comment: hi ftiela, that is not the point here, if you want to find out if a pc is online there are better solutions, i merely use this to show the use of stdout and to avoid other comments, no this is not THE way to use it but it is reliable and works

Comment: yes, i know it's not the point here, but there are some circumstances where checking if you have a "Reply from" doesn't mean that the host is up: the reply from could come from the router or your host (e.g. [http://serverfault.com/questions/131136/ping-replies-from-same-computer-with-destination-host-unreachable-no-route](http://serverfault.com/questions/131136/ping-replies-from-same-computer-with-destination-host-unreachable-no-route). I think it's better to check the status of the reply, not just the "Reply from" string.

Comment: if one would use this technique you are probably right, the problem i face most of the time i need to check if pc's are up is that i need to check hundreds of pc's in e few minutes. not yet found a solution for that problem